# TextView in a LinearLayout that is set in a ScrollVew getting squeezed

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

Going crazy with this one here,(just to be clear: I looked at all the questions here on stackoverflow regarding "scrollview not working" and none of them helped). The following is a short version of what I'm trying to do

```
 <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/week_View"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monday" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monday" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Monday" />.....
        .............
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Textview is repeated multiple more times inside the linearLayout if that is not cleared and I want it to scroll horizontally. What I'm getting is:

[image]

You see the textView at the end getting "squeezed" and the rest of the textviews are not even displayed and scrollview doesn't go left or right. What am I doing incorrectly? (The scrollview is wrapped in a RelativeLayout).

Comment: What are you wanting there? Did you possibly mean for your `LinearLayout`'s `orientation` to be `vertical`? Or maybe you want a `HorizontalScrollView` instead?

Comment: @MikeM. I want to be able scroll horizontal -sorry was not clear there

Comment: `ScrollView` scrolls vertically. You want a `HorizontalScrollView` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScrollViews are always vertical, meaning they go up and down. Use a HorizontalScrollView instead.

Comment: what a god damn miss- felt it will be something crazy simple -thank you guys (y)

Answer (score 1):

As you have got **n** number of textViews its better to use

> a recyclerview with horizontal layout manager as it wont create memories of all textviews at one go

or,

> you can use a horizontalScrollView to scroll them horizontally..

ScrollView scrolls vertically